# SQL Statement Error in Sqlite near"."

Tags: sqlite

I keep getting this error ***near ".": syntax error:*** for the following SQL statement in SQLLite.  Trying to update the price in one table if its id exists in another table which would have the new price

```
UPDATE tbl_tempwork SET tbl_tempwork.tempwork_productwholesale = 
tbl_pricelevel.pricelevel_wholesale FROM tbl_pricelevel WHERE 
tbl_pricelevel.pricelevel_productid = tbl_tempwork.tempwork_productid
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have any sort of update join syntax.  But you can proceed as you might with Oracle, and do the update using a correlated subquery on the `tbl_pricelevel` table.

```
UPDATE tbl_tempwork
SET tempwork_productwholesale = (SELECT pricelevel_wholesale
                                 FROM tbl_pricelevel
                                 WHERE pricelevel_productid =
                                       tbl_tempwork.tempwork_productid)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE tbl_tempwork SET tbl_tempwork.tempwork_productwholesale = tbl_pricelevel.pricelevel_wholesale 
where exists (select 1 FROM tbl_pricelevel WHERE tbl_pricelevel.pricelevel_productid = tbl_tempwork.tempwork_productid)
```